# How to collect data from json file and then add those separetely in a component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, antd

I am using ant design for manupulating and showing my data. Here my json file is,

**[
{
"name":"Dr. John Doe",
"org":"Kings London Hospital",
"availibility":{
"sun":"10:00 AM - 06:00 PM",
"wed":"06:00 PM - 09:00 PM"
},
"visitDurationInMin":15
},
{
"name":"Dr. Mary Ellis",
"org":"ABC Hospital",
"availibility":{
"sun":"10:00 AM - 06:00 PM",
"mon":"09:00 PM - 11:00 PM",
"thu":"11:00 AM - 02:00 PM"
},
"visitDurationInMin":15}
]**

I am trying to collect all of these from that file and output those separately into a component.

my component code is,

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Layout, Descriptions, Calendar, Select , Modal } from "antd";
import Slot from './slot';
import { useDispatch , useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectViewDate, selectViewSlots, setViewSlots } from "../../features/userSlice";
import Data from '../../data/data.json';


const Doctorinfo = ({Data}) => {
  //  constructor(props){
  //      super(props);
  //      this.state = {
  //         viewSlot: false
  //       };
  //  }

  console.log(Data);
 
  const { Option } = Select;
  const { Content } = Layout;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const isViewSlot = useSelector(selectViewSlots);
  const isViewDate = useSelector(selectViewDate);
  const viewSlotHandler = () => {
    // this.setState({
    //     viewSlot:true
    // })

    dispatch(setViewSlots(true));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {isViewDate ? <Content style={{ padding: "0 50px" }}>
        <Descriptions title="Doctor Details">
          <Descriptions.Item label="Name">Anwar Hossain</Descriptions.Item>
          <Descriptions.Item label="Expertise In">
            Neurologist
          </Descriptions.Item>
        </Descriptions>
        <h1>Available Date</h1>
        <Calendar onSelect={viewSlotHandler} />
      </Content>:""}
      {isViewSlot ? <Slot/> : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Doctorinfo;
```

i am trying to get name, availability and visitDuration. After getting i need to get availability time separately like:-

Availability: Sunday

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but in order to get data from JSON-file you can use this:

```
fetch('path/to/your/data.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Of course, you can use async/await for that as well. You can fetch the data in React.useEffect hook:

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch('path/to/your/data.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setData(data));
}, []);
```

Thus, you fetch the data once during the mount phase, store it in the state so you can have an access to it.